# Convert Existing DynamoDB Tables to Global Tables

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

We got an existing DynamoDB table that we would like to make it global. I have done for tables from scratch, but looks like we cannot convert existing tables to global. Is there any workaround to do the same?

Comment: no, you will have to create new table and then migrate existing data.

Comment: Is it possible to backup existing table, create new table, make it global and restore data to new table?

Comment: i am afraid, no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recently(`11/21/2019`) AWS supported global table conversion for existing table with UI/cli/api.
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-convert-your-single-region-amazon-dynamodb-tables-to-global-tables/

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately its not possible to simply convert the table. What you can do is:

1. Export the data from the table into S3 using Data Pipeline
2. Create a brand new empty table and make it global
3. Import the data into the empty table from S3 using Data Pipeline. This will replicate the data across all global instances using streams